# Unity C# ScreenToWorldPoint 2D setting object Z axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

```
touchMarkerObjects[fingerId].transform.position = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(fingerId).position);
```

When I use this line of code it's setting the touchMarkerObjects Z position to -1308 which makes it not render. The camera is at 0,0,0 and is set to Orthographic. Even if I add a line after or try to use only the X/Y of ScreenToWorldPoint in a Vector3 for the transform.position change it still sets the value to -1308.

How should I go about using this to update the objects position without having the Z index affected?

Thanks, I'm certain it's a relatively simple thing I'm overlooking. I hope this is the easiest way to relay the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On start, get the default `z` axis of your GameObject.
Save the value from `mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(fingerId).position);` to a temporary variable. Overwrite the z-axis of the result with that original/default variable before using it. If the z axis of your GameObjects is `0`, simple overwrite it with `0`.

```
float defaultZ = 0f;
```

Or

```
float defaultZ = touchMarkerObjects[...].transform.position.z;
```

then

```
Vector3 tempValue = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(fingerId).position);
tempValue.z = defaultZ;
touchMarkerObjects[fingerId].transform.position = tempValue;
```

Comment: Thanks so much that's what I was looking for. I wrote a bit of code to default the Z value earlier and definitely messed something up. 

I appreciate it, just one of those issues that wasn't standing out to me.